# Can a ToggleButton change the functionality of other buttons in the same Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Summed up, can a ToggleButton change what other buttons in the activity do when toggled? If so, a more specific explanation of what I want to do is below:

Basically there are three buttons and a togglebutton. When the togglebutton is toggled, pressing any of the three buttons will take a picture and 'save it' for that button. When untoggled, pressing any of the three buttons simply displays their images. I think I can figure out the camera capture part, but I need some direction when it comes to the togglebutton.

Any help is appreciated and I can explain further if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a boolean such as `isToggleOn` that is `true` or `false` depending on the `ToggleButton`. Then for each of your buttons, you can simply do:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isToggleOn){
            //do one thing
        } else {
            //do other thing
        }      
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, I like this a lot better than my solution, even though it accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: although if it was a spinner or something with more states, yours would definitely be more preferable!

Comment: Good point! Anything more than two states and this wouldn't work very well, but much simpler for a binary sort of state.

Comment: All of the answers helped me out, so thanks everyone. I'm accepting this one only because it's the method I'm going with. The other answers would have worked too!

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is keep a couple flags for each state at the class level, like this:

```
public class MyClass {
   private static final int STATE_SAVE = 0;
   private static final int STATE_DISPLAY = 1;
   private int currentState = STATE_DISPLAY; 
   // I made this default for the example, 
   // you should use what makes sense to your project.
}
```

Then, inside your toggle button, you can set the flag. Paraphrasing this code since I don't have an editor open:

```
toggleButton.setOnToggleListener(new OnToggleListener() {
   @Override
   public void onToggled(boolean toggled) {
      if(toggled) {
         currentState = STATE_SAVE;
      } else {
         currentState = STATE_DISPLAY;
      }
   });
```

Now, when the buttons are clicked, you can switch based on the state to do an action:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      if(currentState == STATE_SAVE) {
         // Save the image.
      } else if (currentState == STATE_DISPLAY) {
         // Display the image.
      }
   });
```

Comment: Man, you basically re-invented the Boolean :D Gotta give you +1 for that, love the enthusiasm :)

Comment: @Vucko Haha, I'm too used to working with Activities/Fragments that can display more than two states, I've gotten used to this sort of thing.

Comment: This answer is amazing! Simple and elegant. +1 for that!

Comment: Yeah, I know. But couldn't have Enum covered this?

Comment: @Vucko Yes, but it wouldn't have changed my answer *too* much.

Comment: You don't need to save the state of the control. All you need is a reference to it, and have the button listeners query the current state of the control to decide what to do.

Comment: @FredK Yes, that's what the accepted answer does. However, this sort of solution might be better for a spinner or something with more than two states.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you definitely can. Very rarely is anything impossible with code!

All you have to do is to change the listener of the three buttons when the togglebutton is pressed. You keep alternating between the listeners each time you toggle.

For your purpose, I'd suggest defining two sets of listeners - two for each of the three buttons and then keep changing between them.